# Cannot get SqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add to work

Tags: asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource

I am trying to change the parameter of an SqlDataSource on the fly, but the code seems to fail, or in other words I seem to fail.

Here is the code:

```
        int id = 0;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RHOGEConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand getId = new SqlCommand(null, conn);
        SqlParameter name = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        name.Value = SelectTeam.SelectedValue;
        getId.Parameters.Add(name);
        /* getId.CommandText = */ //changed to a select statement that gets a number

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            id = (int)getId.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("getId", TypeCode.Int16, Convert.ToString(id)));
```

Now I know that the code to get the number, the lines above SqlDataSource2, works because I printed it on the screen and they appear correct. I also have tried the SqlDataSource2 select command in SQL Management Studio and it produces the correct results. So my best guess is there is a problem in adding the parameter to the parameters list.

```
SELECT [TeamName] FROM [Teams] where PlayerIdent = (select playerId
                from Players where PlayerShirtId = @getId)
```

The above is the select command that works.

Do you agree that the parameter thing is the correct diagnosis, and if so what I should do?

EDIT: I was able to solve this problem the following way.

```
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["getId"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(id);
```

Comment: If at the end you say you have solved the problem then what is left in doubt that needs to be answered

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of

```
SqlParameter name = new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

it should be

```
Parameter name = new Parameter("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, Convert.ToString(id));
```